# SQLite count and get other records in Cordova

Tags: sqlite, cordova

Snippet of my code:

```
var sql = "SELECT name,data, COUNT(name) as 'mycount' FROM floodMaps WHERE name='?' GROUP BY name,data";
             db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql(sql,[flodMapName], function(tx,res){  
                    //console.log(res.rows.item(0).data);
                     console.log(res.rows.item(0).mycount);
                    if(res.rows.item(0).mycount > 0) {
                        console.log('GETTING DATA FROM DB...');
```

It throws an error:

> a statement with no error handler failed: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.

I am trying to count at the same time get the data from a table but unfortunately it's not working. I did my research, I haven't found a good documentation for the [plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage).

This is how I created the table:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){  
    //database
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'demo.db', location: 'default'}); 
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS floodMaps (name text primary key, data text)');
        tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM floodMaps');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Create Table ERROR: ' + error.message);
    }, function() {
        console.log('Table created successfully.');
    });
    //end database
}, false);
```

The whole code is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75734877/sqlcounterror.txt).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the `?` parameter placeholder should *not* be in single quotes.  Try this instead:

```
var sql = "SELECT name, data, COUNT(name) as `mycount` FROM floodMaps WHERE name= ? GROUP BY name, data";
```

Comment: Now it returns `Cannot read property 'mycount' of undefined`.

Comment: Use either backticks around `mycount` or nothing at all.  Sorry, didn't see that there.

Comment: Tried that..same error..I added how I created my table in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need not have to use single quote at all for alias. You can use as follows:

```
SELECT name,data, COUNT(name) as mycount FROM floodMaps WHERE name=?
```

Check out this [official link](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#a-quick-tour) that has sample for count query too.

Comment: I tried that..same error..will you check my whole code?

Comment: @MattMorales Can you check out this basic working sample available in this link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_SQLite and see if it helps?